# Lua Random number generator always produces the same number

Tags: random, lua

I have looked up several tutorials on how to generate random numbers with lua, each said to use math.random(), so I did. however, every time I use it I get the same number every time, I have tried rewriting the code, and I always get the lowest possible number. I even included a random seed based on the OS time. code below.

```
require "math"
math.randomseed(os.time())
num = math.random(0,10)
print(num)
```

Comment: Your code produces different numbers in the Lua demo at https://www.lua.org/demo.html. Comment the `require` line to run it there.

Comment: it might be the program I am using. it is Lua Development tools using eclipse

Comment: You may have to wait one second between runs to see different numbers.

Comment: that's the thing, it ALWAYS gives me the same number, always the lowest one possible.

Comment: @DragonProgram Try doing this: `local seed = os.time() print(seed) math.randomseed(seed)`. Is `seed` the same every time? That being, is `os.time()` returning the same number every time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the random function like this:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
num = math.random() and math.random() and math.random() and math.random(0, 10)
```

This is working fine. An other option would be to improve the built-in random function, described [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial).

Comment: i strongly advise against doing something like this unless you have clear understanding how pseudo random number generators (prng) work.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur why

Answer (score 0):

This might help! I had to use these functions to write a class that generates Nano IDs. I basically used the milliseconds from the os.clock() function and used that for math.randomseed().

```
NanoId = {
  validCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-",

  generate = function (size, validChars)

    local response = ""
    local ms = string.match(tostring(os.clock()), "%d%.(%d+)")
    local temp = math.randomseed(ms)

    if (size > 0 and string.len(validChars) > 0) then
      for i = 1, size do
        local num = math.random(string.len(validChars))

        response = response..string.sub(validChars, num, num)
      end
    end

    return response
    end
}

function NanoId:Generate()
  return self.generate(21, self.validCharacters)
end

-- Runtime Testing

for i = 1, 10 do
    print(NanoId:Generate())
end

--[[ 

Output:

>>> p2r2-WqwvzvoIljKa6qDH
>>> pMoxTET2BrIjYUVXNMDNH
>>> w-nN7J0RVDdN6-R9iv4i-
>>> cfRMzXB4jZmc3quWEkAxj
>>> aFeYCA2kgOx-s4UN02s0s
>>> xegA--_EjEmcDk3Q1zh7K
>>> 6dkVRaNpW4cMwzCPDL3zt
>>> R2Fct5Up5OwnHeExDnqZI
>>> JwnlLZcp8kml-MHUEFAgm
>>> xPr5dULuv48UMaSTzdW5J

]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `math.random()` right after `math.randomseed(os.time())` seems to do it for me.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
math.random() 
num = math.random(0, 10)
print(num)

io.read()
```