# Lua math.random() always gives the same number?

Tags: random, lua, random-seed

I wanted a string to contain 0 or 1 for some project.
So i tried this

```lua
local data = ""
for i=1, 5 do
    data = data .. math.random(2) - 1
end
print(data)
```

This program always gives `10111` as the result. So after searching i got this similar question. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745798/lua-random-number-generator-always-produces-the-same-number)
So I changed my program to like this as mentioned in that program

```lua
local data = ""
for i=1, 5 do
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    data = data .. math.random(2) - 1
end
print(data)
```

And also this

```lua
local data = ""
for i=1, 5 do
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    math.random(2)
    math.random(2)
    math.random(2)
    data = data .. math.random(2) - 1
end
print(data)
```

So when i tried this one also it always gives `11111` or `00000` as the output. Why??
And how to correct it so that I can get random 0 or 1 in my string??

Comment: Consider using `data = data .. math.random(0,1)`, if you too find it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the seed before the loop:

```lua
local data = ""
math.randomseed(os.time())
for i=1, 5 do
    data = data .. math.random(2) - 1
end
print(data)
```

if you reseed or rerun your program, make sure that more than 1 second has passed, as `os.time()` returns the time in seconds, represented by an integer.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I'm wondering why my code doesn't work?

Comment: The loop is executed so fast that `os.time()` can hardly change: it is the time in seconds.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation. I was thinking that it gives milliseconds like other languages. Thanks for correcting me...

Comment: I am not sure if the loop takes more than 1 ms. You can get the time with higher precision [using socket](https://newbedev.com/lua-current-time-in-milliseconds).